# Polynomial root

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

How can I find the root of a polynomial with `FindRoot`? I do not understand what to put in the 2nd argument. I want to find the values that cancel this polynomial:

```
Res = Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}]]
```

I tried

```
FindRoot[Res == 0, {x, 0}]
```

but it returns `x -> 0`.

What is the problem? Is it posssible to search the root by varying the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: Doesn't `Sin[x]` have a root at `x=0`? (Rhetorical question) And the `{x,0}` gives a starting value for `FindRoot` at zero. What did you expect? Moreover, your `Series` is about zero as well.

Comment: Thanks, I thought {x,0} was the vicinity

Comment: Well, it is. The code was meant to find a root near zero and it did. Maybe you'd want to use [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html). Check out also [`RootIntervals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootIntervals.html).

Comment: "How can I find **the root** of a polynomial" <- Which root?  `FindRoot` uses numerical methods such as Newton's method to find one root o an arbitrary function. `NSolve` finds all roots of a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve using FindRoot it is a good idea to Plot the equation so that you get a rough initial estimate of the roots.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}] // Normal, {x, -10, 10}], 
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, y]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]
```

[image]

Now you can eyeball the roots one by one. You see the first one is at roughly -9, the second at -6 and the third at - 3. The rest are approximately 0,3,6 and 9.

```
FindRoot[Evaluate[Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}]]], {x, #}] & /@ {-9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9}

(*{{x ->-8.607051935073798}, {x -> -6.28423715522116}, {x ->-3.141592653060875}, 
{x -> 0.}, {x -> 3.141592653060875}, {x->6.28423715522116}, {x-> 8.607051935073798}}*)
```

Of course as pointed out by Szabolcs, Nsolve is much easier.

```
NSolve[Evaluate[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}] // Normal], x]

(*{{x -> -8.607051935073825}, {x -> -6.284237155221189}, {x ->-3.141592653060874},
{x -> 0}, {x -> 3.141592653060874}, {x -> 6.284237155221189},
{x->-8.607051935073825}}*)
```

Also, as Corey mentions there is a nice command called RootIntervals.